# Unity-iOS; Is there a way to modify Pod file dependencies after export automatically?

Tags: unity-game-engine, podfile

sometimes pod file is getting old versions of my third parties so i am wondering if there is any way of modifying podfile and adding desired dependency versions(eg; firebase 7.0.0) automatically after ios export? I am also wondering why pod file is getting wrong versions aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Firebase, this is normally managed via the External Dependency Manager. This is configured using xml files. In the case of Firebase, this is inside the Firebase package in Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml.

You may have other xml files in your project that are specifying conflicting dependencies perhaps from an old version of Firebase?

Comment: Thank you, i couldn't find any older version references so maybe somehow xcode is holding the older versions ? just trying to think other possibilities.